# Curvature of a curve whose unit tangent creates a constant angle with z-axis

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I have this question:
Consider a curve $\gamma$(s) and its projection to the plane $\beta$(s), i.e
$$\gamma(t) = \begin{bmatrix} f(s)\\ g(s) \\ h(s) \end{bmatrix},  \beta(t) = \begin{bmatrix} f(s) \\ g(s) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
Where s is the arc length parameter for $\gamma$.

1. Is s also the arc length parameter for $\beta$?
2. Let $T$ be the unit tangent vector of $\gamma$. Prove that the angle between $T(s)$ and the z-axis is at least $\frac{\pi}{4}$ iff $|h'(s)|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.
3. Assume $|h'(s)|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ holds for all $s$. Assume there is a constant C so that $$\kappa_{\gamma}\leq C$$ is satisfied everywhere. Prove that the curvature $$\kappa_{\beta}\leq 100C.$$

It would be great if someone could help me with this problem because I have been working on it for quite some time and have no idea how to arrive at the conclusion for part 3. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The $100$ in part 3 is scary, and overkill. Please share your work on 1 and 2 and what you've tried on 3.

Comment: well for 1 I know the arc length parameter of $\gamma$ is given by $$ s = \int^t_0 \sqrt{(f'(u))^2+(g'(u))^2+(h'(u))^2} du$$ and the arc length parameter for $\beta$ is less that or equal to that. Part 2 was pretty trivial since $\gamma$ has arc length parameter s. So from there I thought to calculate the curvature of $\gamma$ and $\beta$ then compare. I don't know where the 100 comes from though. What are your ideas on this problem?

Comment: Relate $T,N$ for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and remember to use the chain rule when you differentiate $T_{\beta}$.

Comment: wait im sorry Ted do you mean $\gamma$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Ok so after calculation of $\kappa_{\beta}$ and $\kappa_{\gamma}$ I obtained $$\kappa_{\beta}\frac{(f'^2+g'^2)^{3/2}}{(f'^2+g'^2+h'^2)^{3/2}} \sqrt{(\frac{g'h''-g''h'}{g''f'-f''g'})^2+(\frac{f'h''-f''h'}{g''f'-f''g'})^2+1} \leq C$$ I am pretty sure this is correct but am failing to make a connection here. Again $|h'|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant $\gamma$. I'm used to calling my curves $\alpha$ :) I'm still confused by the title of this question, as I expected to see a generalized helix (where the angle is in fact *constant*). This computation looks absolutely horrendous. I would suggest a less coordinate-based computation, something like this: $\beta = \gamma - (\gamma\cdot\vec k)\vec k$, so $\beta' = T_{\gamma} - \cos\theta\vec k$. Now, if $\theta$ is in fact constant, $\|\beta'\| = |\sin\theta|$ and we differentiate, easily, again. When $\theta$ is not constant, I still suspect this method leads to something ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer to your third question:

As $s$ is arc length along $\gamma$ we have
$$\kappa_\gamma(s)=|\dot\gamma\times\ddot\gamma|=\sqrt{(\dot g\ddot h-\ddot g\dot h)^2+(\dot h\ddot f-\ddot h\dot f)^2+(\dot f\ddot g-\ddot f\dot g)^2}\ .$$
Along $\beta$ the variable $s$ is no longer arc length; therefore we have to use the formula
$$|\kappa_\beta(s)|={|\dot f\ddot g-\ddot f\dot g|\over(\dot f^2+\dot g^2)^{3/2}}\ .$$

By assumption $\dot h^2(s)\leq{1\over2}$. As $\dot f^2(s)+\dot g^2(s)+\dot h^2(s)\equiv1$ it follows that $\dot f^2(s)+\dot g^2(s)\geq{1\over2}$, so that we can immediately deduce
$$|\kappa_\beta(s)|\leq\sqrt{8}\>\kappa_\gamma(s)$$
for all $s$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer: $$k\gamma=\frac{\mid g'h''-h'g''h'f''-f'h''f'g''-g'f''\mid}{((f')^{2}+(g')^{2}+(h')^{2})^{3/2}}$$ greater and equal to C #.

Thanks to Hieu Hoang who wrote this short equation.

Comment: Please edit your answer using LaTeX. Directions in the FAQ section.

Comment: I improved the LaTeX.  I'm not familiar with the subject, so make sure I haven't introduced any bugs.  I think the term $h'g''h'f''$ might not be right (since $h'$ occurs twice).

Comment: I appreciate your input. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the OP that asks for such an answer. The OP states "assume there is an upper bound on $\kappa_\gamma$ and prove there is an upper bound on $\kappa_\beta$". Yet this solution gives a lower bound  to $\kappa_\gamma$. I don't see why what is here is relevant, but I could just be plain wrong.